# Modify text file with command

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I modify a text file to do the following in 1 command?

I have a text file called `Errors.txt` with the following 3 lines:

```
Error in File /Test1/A.png
Error in File /Test2/B.jpg
Error in File /Test3/C.jpg
```

I want a command to do the following:

1. Find each "Error in File" and replace it with `"/mnt/HD`.
2. Add `"` at the end of each line.
3. Copy each line, add a space and paste the line
4. Replace the last 4 characters of each line with `webp"`.
5. Add `mv` at the beginning of each line.

I want the result to be like:

```
mv "/mnt/HD/Test1/A.png" "/mnt/HD/Test1/A.webp"
mv "/mnt/HD/Test2/B.jpg" "/mnt/HD/Test2/B.webp"
mv "/mnt/HD/Test3/C.jpg" "/mnt/HD/Test3/C.webp"
```

Comment: What is your end goal here? If you intend to actually *run* those `mv` commands in a shell, then inserting literal quotes is the wrong way to go about it

Comment: This will get you partway there: sed -i 's/Error in File /\/mnt/g'  <your filename>

Also look at man pages and examples for the sed and awk commands.

Comment: You need to read up on `sed`: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your questions at face value:

> 1- Find Each {Error in File } and Replace it with {"/mnt}

```
sed 's/Error in File /"\/mnt/' Errors.txt
```

although you actually seem to want

```
sed 's/Error in File /"\/mnt\/HD/' Errors.txt
```

> 2- Add {"} at the end of each line

```
sed 's/$/"/' Errors.txt
```

> 3- Copy each line, add a space and paste the line

```
sed 's/.*/& &/' Errors.txt
```

> 4- replace the last 4 characters of each line by {webp"}

```
sed 's/....$/webp"/' Errors.txt
```

> 5- Add {mv } at the beginning of each line

```
sed 's/^/mv /' Errors.txt
```

So (naively) you could put that all together as

```
sed -e 's/Error in File /"\/mnt\/HD/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/.*/& &/' -e 's/....$/webp"/' -e 's/^/mv /' Errors.txt
```

A less piecemeal approach would be to use *capture groups*, like so

```
sed -E 's;Error in File (.*)(.{4})$;mv "/mnt/HD\1\2" "/mnt/HD\1.webp";' Errors.txt
```

where using `;` as the sed separator allows you to include unescaped `/` characters in the pattern and/or replacement text.

---

**However**, if your goal is to create a set of `mv` commands and pass them to a shell to execute them, I'd suggest something more like

```
sed -n 's;^Error in File ;/mnt/HD;p' Errors.txt | 
  while IFS= read -r f; do echo mv -n -- "${f}" "${f%.*}.webp"; done
```

Here the `sed` command replaces a leading string `Error in file`  with `/mnt/HD` and prints the resulting line to the standard output stream. Then the `while` loop reads whole *lines* (possibly including whitespace or other shell-special characters) and ensures they are properly quoted when passed to the `mv` command.

The shell substitution `${f%.*}` removes the shortest dot suffix from the file - more versatile than just blindly removing the last 4 characters.

Remove the `echo` when you are ready to perform the `mv` commands for real.

Comment: Should these not be `sed -i ...`?

Comment: @AdamBarnes only if the OP really, really wants to lose the original which seems like a needless risk.

Comment: As it stands, for all but your final command, the examples you gave have no effect, which struck me as a little useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing in a little perl one liner:

```
$ perl -lne '/Error in File (.+)\.(...)$/; 
    print "mv \"/mnt/HD$1.$2\" \"/mnt/HD$1.webp\""' Errors.txt 
mv "/mnt/HD/Test1/A.png" "/mnt/HD/Test1/A.webp"
mv "/mnt/HD/Test2/B.jpg" "/mnt/HD/Test2/B.webp"
mv "/mnt/HD/Test3/C.jpg" "/mnt/HD/Test3/C.webp"
```

###### Explanation

- `perl -lne`: the `-n` means "run the perl script given by `-e` on each line of the input file; the `-l` adds a `\n` to each `print` call (i.e. it adds a newline after printing so the next print is on a separate line).
- `/Error in File (.+)\.(...)$/;`: look for `Error in File` followed by a space, and then look for the longest string until a `.` (`\.` will match a literal `.` while `.` alone means "any character") followed by any three characters (`...`) until the end of the line (`$`). The parentheses let
  you "capture" a match and then refer to it as `$1` for the first set of parentheses, `$2` for the second and so on. So after this, the file name is `$1` and the extension is `$2`.
- `print "mv \"/mnt/HD$1.$2\" \"/mnt/HD$1.webp\""`: print out the `mv` command you want.

---

Of course, since you're already using perl, might as well just have it rename the files directly (WARNING: this will actually rename the files):

```
perl -lne '/Error in File (.+)\.(...)$/; 
   rename("/mnt/HD$1.$2", "/mnt/HD$1.webp")' Errors.txt
```

The command above turns this:

```
$ tree /mnt/HD/
/mnt/HD/
├── Test1
│   └── A.png
├── Test2
│   └── B.jpg
└── Test3
    └── C.jpg

4 directories, 3 files
```

into this:

```
$ tree /mnt/HD/
/mnt/HD/
├── Test1
│   └── A.webp
├── Test2
│   └── B.webp
└── Test3
    └── C.webp

4 directories, 3 files
```

---

One more way. If your `Errors.txt` file is *always* exactly as you show, so it always has the exact string `Error in File`  (including a space at the end) and everything after that is a file name whose extension you want t change, you could simply do:

```
$ sed 's/Error in File //' Errors.txt | rename -n 's/...$/webp/'
/Test1/A.png -> /Test1/A.webp
/Test2/B.jpg -> /Test2/B.webp
/Test3/C.jpg -> /Test3/C.webp
```

If that looks correct, run the same command with the `-n` option to actually rename. Or, if you really just want to print out the commands and nothing else, you could do:

```
$ sed 's/Error in File //' Errors.txt | 
  while IFS= read -r file; do 
    printf 'mv "%s" "%s"\n' "$file" "${file%???}"webp; 
  done
mv "/Test1/A.png" "/Test1/A.webp"
mv "/Test2/B.jpg" "/Test2/B.webp"
mv "/Test3/C.jpg" "/Test3/C.webp"
```